# When authenticating with Omniauth, what data should I store in the cookie?

Tags: ruby, oauth, sinatra

I'm using Sinatra and Omniauth (specifically, google oauth2) to serve a website. I'm somewhat confused over what data is safe to store in the cookie and what isn't.

I'm inclined to say that I should simply store an `authorized => true` field in the cookie, once I have confirmed that the AuthHash contains an access token. The cookie is protected using `Rack::Sesssion::Cookie` and `:secret => "some-really-long-and-strong-password"`. Is this thinking correct?

Furthermore, if someone wants to hack the site (i.e. login without actually logging in), all they need to do is successfully break the cookie's secret and make a fake cookie with `authorized => true`, right?

I don't see any value in storing the actual access key stored in the credentials portion of the `Omniauth::AuthHash`, since this seems to be the sensitive information...

Answer (score 2):

> I'm somewhat confused over what data is safe to store in the cookie and what isn't.

In general, this is the worst scenario if someone steals a user cookie:

- Hijack the user's session
- Steal all data contained in the cookie
- Gain unauthorized access

I think what you want to use is a form of authenticity token that you can pass back and forth to verify the authenticity of the user and their requests.

**References**

- [Cross-site Request Forgery on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

I'd check out the sections [Example and characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Example_and_characteristics) and [Prevention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention) in particular.

Comment: Thanks, am I right in saying that "Steal all the data contained in the cookie" is challenging if the cookie's secret is sufficiently strong? As for CSRF with <img> tags, the worst case seems to be that you get the authenticated user to perform unintended actions against that site. If this is a somewhat harmless scenario (i.e. the site doesn't do anything too sensitive) then I wouldn't be overly concerned about this. Same goes for Hijack the user's session.

Comment: You can encrypt the cookie data, which will make it safer.